# How do I interpret model summary of merged models in keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I want to built a  model with many smaller model's output merged as one. I want 146 network taking 17 input each and giving a probability as output. The output of all these network need to be merged and used as single unit .For which I did something like this:

```
def build(layer_str,actv):
        #take the input layer structure and convert it into a list
        layers=layer_str.split("-")
        #print(layers)
        #convert the strings in the list to integer
        layers=list(map(int,layers))
              
        #let's build our model
        model= tf.keras.Sequential()
        
        #we add the first layer and the input layer to our network
        model.add(Dense(layers[1],input_shape=(layers[0],),activation=actv[0]))
        
        #we add the hidden layers 
        for (x,i) in enumerate(layers):
            if(x>1 and x!=(len(layers)-1)):
                model.add(Dense(i,activation=actv[x]))
                
        
        #then add the final layer        
        model.add(Dense(layers[-1],activation=actv[-1]))        
        
        #return the construtcted model
        return model
```

Then, Merged models like this:

```
def Merge_model(layer,act,data,label,lr,epochs,batch_size):
    model_list=[]
    for i in range(146):
        model=nn.build(layer,act)
        model_list.append(model)
    merged_layers = concatenate([model_list[i].output for i in range(146)])
    x = merged_layers
    out = Activation('sigmoid')(x)
    merged_model = Model([model_list[i].input for i in range(146)], [out])
    print(merged_model.summary())
    merged_model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])
    result,predictions=nn.train_eval(data,label,merged_model,lr,epochs,batch_size)
data=np.random.rand(10,146,17)
data=[d for d in data]
label=np.random.randint(0,1,(10,146,1))
label=[lb for lb in label]
print(len(label[0]))
lr=0.01
epochs=100
batch_size=16
Merge_model("17-7-1",["relu","sigmoid"],data,label,lr,epochs,batch_size)
```

I get the model summary as such But do not understand what to make of it. What is supposed to be my  trainig data and layer's shape?
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1juffdLY0i9f9rgldKfHG_MYXCK8wBV09/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You can merge different models using Keras API that is `concat = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([dense_1, dense_2])`, where,dense_1 and dense_2 are outputs of two different models. For more details refer the [Tensorflow doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/concatenate). Thanks!

Comment: @TFer umm I did that but now I don't understand what should my input shape and output shape should be?

Comment: input shape to concatenate layer can be obtained from output shape of the each model. Thanks!

Comment: @TFer Sorry for your inconvenience but I still cannot understand where I have gone wrong. I have created a new question at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68222082/what-should-my-train-data-input-and-input-label-shape-be . Please, can you check it and reply